# loop to create N equal payments in XSLT

Tags: xml, loops, templates, xslt

I am pretty new in this language and need help by creating a loop in xslt. I have an XML with info below:

```
 <Number_of_Payments>12</Number_of_Payments>
 <First_Payment_Date>28-10-2020</First_Payment_Date>
 <Monthly_Payment>760,00</Monthly_Payment>
```

And I need to transform this to a recurrent monthly payment (12 payments of 760). So far I have the first payment in xslt:

```
<paymentplan>
    <loanpaymentplantype>Flat</loanpaymentplantype>
    <intervaltype>StartOfMonth</intervaltype>
    <interval>1</interval>
    <startdate>
      <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
                  <xsl:with-param name="DateTimeStr" select="Account/First_Payment_Date"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </startdate>
    <maturitydate>
      <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
        <xsl:with-param name="DateTimeStr" select="Account/Last_Payment_Date"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </maturitydate>
    <numpayments>
      <xsl:value-of select="Account/Number_of_Payments"/>
    </numpayments>
    <payments>
      <payment>
          <paymentdate>
              <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
                  <xsl:with-param name="DateTimeStr" select="Account/First_Payment_Date"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
              <!--<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(First_Payment_Date, 7, 4),'-',substring(First_Payment_Date, 4, 2),'-',substring(First_Payment_Date, 1, 2))"/>-->
          </paymentdate>
          <amount>
              <xsl:value-of select="translate(Account/Monthly_Payment, ',', '.')"/>
          </amount>
          <principalamount>
              <xsl:value-of select="translate(Account/Monthly_Payment, ',', '.')"/>
          </principalamount>
          <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
      </payment>
    </payments>
```

This is the Output that I get:

```
<paymentplan>
            <loanpaymentplantype>Flat</loanpaymentplantype>
            <intervaltype>StartOfMonth</intervaltype>
            <interval>1</interval>
            <startdate>2020-11-01</startdate>
            <maturitydate>2021-10-01</maturitydate>
            <numpayments>12</numpayments>
            <payments>
               <payment>
                  <paymentdate>2020-11-01</paymentdate>
                  <amount>760.00</amount>
                  <principalamount>760.00</principalamount>
                  <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
               </payment>
            </payments>
         </paymentplan>
```

What I would need is 12 payments on the paymentplan:

```
<payment>
                  <paymentdate>2020-11-01</paymentdate>
                  <amount>760.00</amount>
                  <principalamount>760.00</principalamount>
                  <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
               </payment>
<payment>
                  <paymentdate>2020-12-01</paymentdate>
                  <amount>760.00</amount>
                  <principalamount>760.00</principalamount>
                  <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
               </payment>
<payment>
                  <paymentdate>2021-01-01</paymentdate>
                  <amount>760.00</amount>
                  <principalamount>760.00</principalamount>
                  <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
               </payment>
<payment>
                  <paymentdate>2021-02-01</paymentdate>
                  <amount>760.00</amount>
                  <principalamount>760.00</principalamount>
                  <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
               </payment>
<payment>
                  <paymentdate>2021-03-01</paymentdate>
                  <amount>760.00</amount>
                  <principalamount>760.00</principalamount>
                  <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
               </payment>
<payment>
                  <paymentdate>2021-04-01</paymentdate>
                  <amount>760.00</amount>
                  <principalamount>760.00</principalamount>
                  <fixedinterest>0</fixedinterest>
               </payment>
```

And so on...

Comment: Well, which version of XSLT do you use, which XSLT processor? In XSLT 3 (supported by Saxon 10 or 11 on Java, .NET, C/C++, Python, by Saxon-JS 2 for Node.js and in the browser) you can literally use `<xsl:iterate select="1 to 12">...</xsl:iterate>`.

Comment: In addition to the XSLT version supported by your processor, we need to know how you want to handle cases where the first payment is on the 31st of the month, for example.

Comment: Thank you, version is 1.0 and all payments must proceed on the 1st day of each month up to 12 months.

Comment: Well, your input has `<First_Payment_Date>28-10-2020</First_Payment_Date>` - so please explain the exact logic you use to get to `<startdate>2020-11-01</startdate>`. In fact, it would be helpful if you also edit your question and make it a [mcve] instead of snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could use as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <payments>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-payments">
            <xsl:with-param name="start-year" select="2020"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="start-month" select="11"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="number-of-payments" select="12"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="760"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </payments>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-payments">
    <xsl:param name="start-year"/>
    <xsl:param name="start-month"/>
    <xsl:param name="number-of-payments"/>
    <xsl:param name="amount"/>
    <xsl:if test="$number-of-payments > 0">
        <payment>
            <paymentdate>
                <xsl:value-of select="$start-year"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($start-month, '-00')"/>
                <xsl:text>-01</xsl:text>
            </paymentdate>
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($amount, '#,##0.00')"/>
            </amount>
        </payment>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:variable name="m" select="12*$start-year + $start-month" />
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-payments">
            <xsl:with-param name="start-year" select="floor($m div 12)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="start-month" select="$m mod 12 + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="number-of-payments" select="$number-of-payments - 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="$amount"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payments>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2020-11-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2020-12-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-01-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-02-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-03-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-04-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-05-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-06-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-07-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-08-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-09-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
   <payment>
      <paymentdate>2021-10-01</paymentdate>
      <amount>760.00</amount>
   </payment>
</payments>
```